# I have so many problems with ubuntu 21.10 impish version? Everytime we update ubuntu our php or apache2 environment get stucked?

Tags: apache2, php, 21.10

Recently i Upgraded my ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10. when update get finished i got an notification like you have held broken package to resolve please use partial update. I updated again i got an error or new update like arround 12 mb update. I started upgrading i got this

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

php7.2-cli: Depends: libpcre3 (>= 2:8.41) but 2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) but 7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 is to be installed
Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
```

I Don't understand why every time we got stucked with php only. I am a web developer Working for a startup they have so many projects on php7.2. Now i am stucked everytime with every update like problem with composer package, php versions issues and lastly for apache2.

*I want to ask you why ubuntu are not supporting php versions*.

**By the way here is my problem.**

1. Apache2 cann't starts

   ```
   Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
   See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
   apache-htcacheclean.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
   Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
   Processing triggers for ufw (0.36.1-1) ...
   Rules updated for profile 'Apache'
   Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'
   Firewall reloaded
   ```
2. I try to resolved by terminal i got this

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   Calculating upgrade... Done
   The following packages have been kept back:
     php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-curl php7.2-fpm php7.2-intl php7.2-json
     php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-xml
     php7.2-zip
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded
   ```
3. I used this

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install -f

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.`
   ```
4. Then i tried this

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg --configure -a

   $ sudo apt-get install -f

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded
   ```

**Here is my term.log when my system upgraded**

```
Log started: 2021-10-10  01:46:59 dpkg: warning: downgrading php7.2-zip from 7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to
7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (Reading database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading database
... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40% (Reading
database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading database
... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80% (Reading
database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ... 262970 files and
directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../00-php7.2-zip_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-zip (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over
(7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-xml from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../01-php7.2-xml_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-xml (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over
(7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-readline from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../02-php7.2-readline_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-readline (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-opcache from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../03-php7.2-opcache_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-opcache (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-mysql from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../04-php7.2-mysql_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-mysql (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-mbstring from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../05-php7.2-mbstring_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-mbstring (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-json from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../06-php7.2-json_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-json (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-cli from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../07-php7.2-cli_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-cli (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over
(7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-fpm from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../08-php7.2-fpm_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-fpm (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over
(7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-intl from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../09-php7.2-intl_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-intl (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... dpkg: warning:
downgrading php7.2-common from
7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00 to 7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Preparing to unpack .../10-php7.2-common_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking php7.2-common (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
over (7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00) ... (Reading
database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database
... 25% (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading
database ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database
... 65% (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading
database ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database
... 262971 files and directories currently installed.) Removing
libicu65:amd64 (65.1-1+0~20200223.8+debian9~1.gbp519cf3) ... Selecting
previously unselected package php7.2-curl. (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading database
... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading
database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database
... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading
database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database
... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ... 262955 files
and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../php7.2-curl_7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-curl (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.2-common (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.2-opcache (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.2-zip (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.2-curl (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/curl.ini with new
version Setting up php7.2-json
(7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting up php7.2-mysql
(7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting up
php7.2-mbstring (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting
up php7.2-intl (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting up
php7.2-xml (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting up
php7.2-readline (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting
up php7.2-cli (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Setting up
php7.2-fpm (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... NOTICE: Not
enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default. NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in
Apache2 do: NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif NOTICE: a2enconf
php7.2-fpm NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have
apache2 package installed. Processing triggers for libc-bin
(2.33-0ubuntu5) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for php7.2-cli
(7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... Processing triggers for
php7.2-fpm (7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ... NOTICE: Not
enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default. NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in
Apache2 do: NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif NOTICE: a2enconf
php7.2-fpm NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have
apache2 package installed. Log ended: 2021-10-10  01:49:13
```

**This is my debian php search result**

```
dpkg -l | grep -E "sury|debian9"
```

````
rc  libapache2-mod-php7.2 7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module) 
ii  libapr1:amd64 1.7.0-6+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+2            amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Library ```
ii  libargon2-1:amd64                        0~20190702-0.1+0~20190710.3+debian9~1.gbp2fb167 amd64       memory-hard hashing function - runtime library 
ii  libbrotli-dev:amd64 1.0.9-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        library implementing brotli encoder and decoder (development files) I need only php7.2 and apache2. I was frustrated and manually deleted some php versions directory so i can't purge now.
ii  libbrotli1:amd64                         1.0.9-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        library implementing brotli encoder and decoder (shared libraries) 
ii  libicu65:amd64                          65.1-1+0~20200223.8+debian9~1.gbp519cf3         amd64        International Components for Unicode It happens because i have multiple php versions like php7.2 , php7.4 and php8.0. I upgraded from software update GUI. I thoughti was easy but i mistaken.
ii  libpcre16-3:amd64            2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - 16 bit runtime files 
ii  libpcre2-16-0:amd64                          10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library - 16 bit runtime files 
ii  libpcre2-32-0:amd64                          10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library - 32 bit runtime files 
ii  libpcre2-8-0:amd64                           10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library- 8 bit runtime files 
ii  libpcre2-dev:amd64                           10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library - development files 
ii  libpcre2-posix2:amd64                        10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1            amd64        New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library - posix-compatible runtime files
ii  libpcre3:amd64                               2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files 
ii  libpcre3-dev:amd64                           2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - development files 
ii  libpcre32-3:amd64                            2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - 32 bit runtime files 
ii  libpcrecpp0v5:amd64                          2:8.44-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - C++ runtime files 
ii  libsodium23:amd64                            1.0.18-1+0~20191009.1+debian9~1.gbpb6823f       amd64        Network communication, cryptography and signaturing library 
ii  libzip4:amd64  1.7.3-1+0~20210114.10+debian9~1.gbp4c125d       amd64        library for reading, creating, and modifying zip archives (runtime) 
ii  php-common                                   2:84+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1               all          Common files for PHP packages 
ii  php-curl                                    2:8.0+84+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           all          CURL module for PHP [default] 
ii  php7.0-cli                                7.0.33-54+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language 
ii  php7.0-common                                 7.0.33-54+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP 
ii  php7.0-json      7.0.33-54+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        JSON module for PHP 
ii  php7.0-opcache                                7.0.33-54+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP 
ii  php7.0-readline                             7.0.33-54+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        readline module for PHP 
ii  php7.1-cli                                    7.1.33-41+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language 
ii  php7.1-common                                 7.1.33-41+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP 
ii  php7.1-json      7.1.33-41+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        JSON module for PHP 
ii  php7.1-opcache                                7.1.33-41+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP 
ii  php7.1-readline                             7.1.33-41+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        readline module for PHP rc  php7.2-cli                                    7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language 
ii  php7.2-common                                 7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP rc  php7.2-curl      7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        CURL module for PHP rc  php7.2-fpm                                    7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary) 
ii  php7.2-intl                                   7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-json                    7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        JSON module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-mbstring                               7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-mysql                                  7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        MySQL module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-opcache                                7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP rc  php7.2-readline                             7.2.34-23+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1          amd64        readline module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-xml                                    7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP 
ii  php7.2-zip            7.2.34-25+0~20210923.65+debian9~1.gbpa3cd00     amd64        Zip module for PHP 
ii  php7.3-cli                                    7.3.31-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language 
ii  php7.3-common                                 7.3.31-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP 
ii  php7.3-json      7.3.31-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        JSON module for PHP 
ii  php7.3-opcache                                7.3.31-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP 
ii  php7.3-readline                             7.3.31-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        readline module for PHP 
ii  php7.4-cli                                    7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language 
ii  php7.4-common                                 7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP rc  php7.4-gd        7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        GD module for PHP 
ii  php7.4-json                                   7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        JSON module for PHP 
ii  php7.4-mysql                                  7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        MySQL module for PHP 
ii  php7.4-opcache                                7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP 
ii  php7.4-readline                             7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        readline module for PHP rc  php7.4-xml                                    7.4.24-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, XML, and XSL module for PHP 
ii  php8.0-common               8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP 
ii  php8.0-curl      8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        CURL module for PHP 
rc  php8.0-gd                                     8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        GD module for PHP 
rc  php8.0-mysql                                  8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        MySQL module for PHP 
rc  php8.0-xml                                    8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1           amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, XML, and XSL module for PHP
````

I need only php7.2 and apache2. I was frustrated and manually deleted some php versions directory so i can't purge now.

It happens because i have multiple php versions like php7.2 , php7.4 and php8.0. I upgraded from software update GUI. I thoughti was easy but i mistaken.

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E "sury|debian9"` to the question. Which version of PHP do you need in 21.10 system?

Comment: i need only php7.2. i ussed lots of php version in past so now i messed. I updated my query. `dpkg -l | grep -E "sury|debian9" ' search result added.

Comment: i used smart package manager "aptitude" but still getting error

Comment: can we start chat

Comment: i got another error

Comment: `E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

Comment: Full error output is needed, please upload it to pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ezRjD7cV

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YNRstnCv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130743/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-ronny-dsouza).